# La forme « médecienne »

Tags: vocabulaire, histoire, professions

Pourquoi la forme « [médecienne](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9decienne) » pour la femme-médecin est-elle rare, voire désuète ?

Comment: Le wiktionnaire n'est pas une source très fiable (comparé à Wikipédia par exemple). Ils ont tendance à inventer des mots, ou bien à considérer que si un auteur utilise une fois ou deux un néologisme alors il faut le rajouter dans le dictionnaire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Médecienne* est un mot que l'on rencontrait dans le français du moyen-âge mais qui n'a pas survécu.

> Tout le monde fait esmerveillier
>   En Salerne, n’a Monspellier
>   N’a si bonne fisicienne
>   Tant soit bonne médecienne
>   Tous ceux sanes (guéris)
>   cui tu atouches
>
> Gauthier de Coinsi, *Miracles de Notre-Dame*,  d'après Mélanie Lipinska, *Histoire des femmes médecins depuis l’Antiquité jusqu’à nos jours*, Librairie G. Jacques et Cie, 1900, p.117

J'y vois plusieurs raisons :

- l'impossibilité pour les femmes d'exercer la profession de médecin pendant des siècles a tôt fait tomber ce mot dans les oubliettes. *Médecienne* est absent de tous les dictionnaires de l'Académie. On trouve *méd**i**cienne* dans le [dictionnaire du moyen français](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/m%C3%A9dicienne).
- *médecienne* est le féminin de l'hypothétique *médecien* (de garde ;-) ) qui ne s'écrit pas (ou plus) comme ça.
- le féminin régulier *médecine* a aussi été utilisé pour femme-médecin, cf [Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/medecine) mais entre en conflit avec la science du même nom et le sens, perdu en français moderne, de médicament.

Parmi les synonymes oubliés de médecin acceptant les deux genres, on trouve aussi [médecineur/médecineresse](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/m%C3%A9decineur) et [mire](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/mire)/[miresse](http://micmap.org/dicfro/previous/dictionnaire-godefroy/341/5/miresse)

Answer (score 0):

Dire que la forme `médecienne` est rare voire désuète est le moins qu'on puisse dire, car, semble-t-il, elle n'existe dans aucun des principaux dictionnaires connus depuis le XVIIIe siècle (Académie, Littré, Robert, Larousse), ni même dans le dictionnaire reconstitué du français médiéval (DMF).

En admettant qu'on le trouve dans des écrits très anciens, ce terme doit donc être plutôt considéré comme un terme de "patois", c'est à dire localisé sur un territoire restreint, peut-être en langue d'Oc médiévale, mais non comme un substantif appartenant ou ayant appartenu à la langue française proprement dite.

Comment: La théorie d'une origine « patoisante », si tant est qu'elle puisse avoir un sens pour de l'ancien français, est difficilement défendable. *Médecienne* de par sa forme est un mot savant, utilisé par des locuteurs maîtrisant probablement la latin. En langue d'oil, les dérivés populaires de *medicus* sont *mire*, *mège*, *mide* etc. En langue d'oc, le latin *medicus* a donné *mège* ou *metge* qui n'ont aucune ressemblance avec *médecienne*.